# Working with STL file in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d

I have an STL file that represents a shape that is approximately 4x4x4".

I am trying to create a simple algorithm in C# that can read the STL file and tell me for each point in the X, Y and Z axis if that point is part of the shape or not.  True/False for each point in that cube - that's it.

Any suggestions of what my best approach would be?

Would I be best off trying to read the STL file directly (hopefully with the help of some library) - or would I be better of converting the STL file into some other format before processing it in my code?

Thanks in advance - I look forward to any help you can provide this 3D newbie!

Comment: There's a project on CodeProject.com, and when you search there's a lot more available. Try that first and ask specific questions here.

Comment: Thanks Henk - can you direct me to a link?  What would I even be searching for exactly?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it directly. The format is so simple that a library is probably more trouble than it's worth (with the caveat that I've never tried it).

Comment: Thanks Marcelo.  I've been looking into the format and you're right - it appears that the format is almost TOO simple.  It actually raises a more complicated question which is what library might be able to read the STL file and detect the "solid" shapes that are described.  I would rather not try to do that - as it sounds quite complicated... :(  Someone must have already solved this problem - no?

Comment: I guess - said another way - can anyone recommend an easy way to detect water tight shapes within an STL file in C#?  :)

Comment: @eejai42: That's a completely different question that you should raise separately.